# SAP CAPM association modeling

Tags: hana, sap-business-technology-platform, sap-cap

I am new to SAP CAPM modeling. I have a requirement of tables as below.

`VOUCHERPROGRAM`

| PROGRAM_ID | VOUCHER_DESC |
| --- | --- |
| 1ax-0fd | voucher1 |

`VOUCHERDENOM`

| PROGRAM_ID | VOUCHER_DENO |
| --- | --- |
| 1ax-0fd | vouchxs5 |
| 1ax-0fd | vouchxs5 |

Based on above table I created entities like

```
entity VoucherProgram: managed {
    key PROGRAM_ID : UUID  @(Core.Computed : true);
    VOUCHER_DESC : String(2000);
    DENOM: Association to VoucherDenomination on DENOM.PROGRAM_ID = PROGRAM_ID
```

```
entity VoucherDenomination: managed {
    PROGRAM_ID: String;
    VOUCHER_DENO: string
    VOUCHER_PROGRAMS: Association to many VoucherProgram on VOUCHER_PROGRAMS.PROGRAM_ID=$self.PROGRAM_ID
```

Based on entities created, now am able to insert a row into VoucherDenomination with random programId. How  can I achieve like a foreign key such that insertion into VoucherDenomination fails when random program id is given rather than one program_id in VoucherProgram table

Comment: Any answers or help.?